# Conditional statement in gdal calc

Tags: python, gdal, conditional

I have this statement working in arcpy but I want this to implement in gdal, especially with gdal_calc, if possible.

```
Rastercalc = Con(((C-B) > 2) & (B > 100), A, Con(((A-D)>15) & ((A-E)>15),0,A))
```

I already tried writing this in gdal_calc as below but the output is not the same

```
gdal_calc.py --format GTiff --type Byte -A %s --A_band %s -B %s -C %s -D %s --D_band %s -E %s --E_band %s --outfile %s --calc="A*((C-B) > 2)+ (A*((A-E) < 30)* ((A-D) < 30))* ((C-B) <= 2)" --overwrite
```

I even tried this using numpy.where() with no luck

```
outcalc = numpy.where(numpy.logical_and((C - B) > 2, B > 100), A, numpy.where(numpy.logical_and((A - D) > 30, (A - E) > 30), 0, A))
```

Would somebody knows if this possible in gdal_calc (this is preferred way) but any other option in gdal would be great including numpy.where()?

---

I am pasting the part of my script and sampled results. The input data is actually a multiband (14 bands) dataset.

script:

--arcpy implementation----

```
            A = Raster(infile + os.sep + 'Layer_'+str(b))
            D = Raster(infile + os.sep + 'Layer_'+str(b-1))
            E = Raster(infile + os.sep + 'Layer_'+str(b+1))
            B = Raster(tempMed)
            C = Raster(tempMean)
            Rastercalc = Con(((C-B) > 2) & (B > 100), A, Con(((A-D)>15) & ((A-E)>15),0,A))
            Rastercalc.save(out_band)

            ##------ gdal_calc implementation------

            runCalc     = 'gdal_calc.py --format GTiff --type Byte -A %s --A_band %s -B %s -C %s -D %s --D_band %s \
                        -E %s --E_band %s --outfile %s --calc="(((C.astype(int16)-B > 2) * (B.astype(int16) > 100)) *\
                        ((A.astype(int16)-D <= 15) * (A.astype(int16)-E <= 15))) * A" --overwrite'\
                        % (infile, b, tempMed,tempMean,infile, b-1,infile, b+1, out_band)
```

---

spectral profiles of original layer, layer produced in arcpy, and gdal.

original

[image]

arcpy

[image]

gdal

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Con(((C-B) > 2) & (B > 100), A, Con(((A-D)>15) & ((A-E)>15),0,A))`

Trying to interpret the `arcpy` `Con` statement:

```
Where (C-B > 2) AND (B > 100) : A
Otherwise, where (A-D > 15) AND (A-E > 15) : 0
Elsewhere : A
```

To me this looks like it could be reduced to the following:

```
Where (C-B <= 2) AND (B <= 100) AND (A-D > 15) AND (A-E > 15) : 0
Elsewhere : A
```

Or inversely:

```
Where (C-B > 2) AND (B > 100) AND (A-D <= 15) AND (A-E <= 15) : A
Elsewhere : 0
```

This could be accomplished with the `outcalc`:

```
"((C-B > 2) * (B > 100) * (A-D <= 15) * (A-E <= 15)) * A"
```

The idea is each comparison yields 1 or 0 for True or False. The multiplication train acts as a progressive masking operation which only yields 1 where all conditionals are met. This value of 1 is multiplied by A to yield A and 0 times A equals 0.

Comment: Thank you Logan for prompt answer with explanation but this is still not producing valid result. I even tried separating the condition in two blocks as below but still got wrong output. (((C-B > 2) * (B > 100)) * ((A-D <= 30) * (A-E <= 30))) * A

Comment: @Devdai What is wrong about the output? If these are Byte (unsigned 8-bit) images there is the potential for integer underflow. C-B "should" return -3 but returns 253 because negative integers can't be represented.

If that seems like the reason, then you could cast the arrays in memory to a signed 16-bit for the conditional checks and recast the result to uint8. It would look something like `"(((C.astype(int16)-B.astype(int16) > 2) .... *A).astype(uint8)"` Watch your parentheses and cast the final result to uint8. This is within `numpy` namespace so don't use `numpy.uint8`.

Comment: Please see below for detail response. Arc produced the valid result (removing spike is the intention) and gdal produced entirely different output.

Comment: @Devdai I don't understand why the output image has 14 bands. It should have 1 band. It should also be a GTiff, from what your code says. You are showing a `.img` file. Try to delete the output file and run again. In some cases GDAL will modify existing rasters rather than write a completely new file. Also, please move your response into an edit in the original question and delete the answer you provided.

Comment: oh! my apology for the incomplete script/information. The equation is implemented to a band at a time (loop through) and later stacked using gdal_merge to match input properties. I verified the output of individual band with the final 14 band image and the result is matching.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the equation. Thanks @Logan for the help. I had to break the equation to make it work.

---

runCalc1 =

`'gdal_calc.py --format GTiff --type Byte -A %s --A_band %s -B %s -C %s -D %s --D_band %s -E %s --E_band %s --outfile %s --calc="((C-B <= 2) * (A-D >= 15) * (A-E >= 15)) * 15" --overwrite' % (infile, b, tempMed,tempMean,infile, b-1,infile, b+1, tempB1b)`

runCalc2 =

`'gdal_calc.py --format GTiff --type Byte -A %s --A_band %s -B %s -C %s -D %s --outfile %s --calc="((C-B > 2) * (B > 100) * (D != 15)) * A" --overwrite' % (infile, b, tempMed,tempMean, tempB1b, out_band)`