# Python alternative for ArcPy's Con tool?

Tags: python, rasterio

I'm wondering if there is a method to perform a function similar to ArcGIS's `Con` tool, using open source options in Python.

I have two rasters, one that shows veloticty and one that shows detph. With ArcPy  it is easy to get a new raster:

```
Con(((detph >= 1) | (veloticty >= 1)|(detph*veloticty>=0.5)), 3,(Con(((detph >= 0.4) | (veloticty >= 0.4)|(detph*veloticty>=0.08)), 2,1)))
```

I would like to do with open source options in Python.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/232524/8104

Answer (score 2):

Try reading the rasters into numpy arrays using rasterio, [numpy where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of Con and then [write the output as raster](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/writing.html).

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio

demfile = '/home/bera/GIS/DEM50m/nh_68_4.tif'

dem = rasterio.open(demfile)
demarr = dem.read()
onezero = np.random.randint(2, size=demarr.shape)

newarr = np.where(onezero==1, demarr, np.where(demarr>500, 1000, 0))
newarr = newarr.astype('float32')

with rasterio.Env():
    profile = dem.profile
    with rasterio.open('/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/dem_modified.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(newarr)
```

[image]